# "DELETE TOP (1) FROM @TEMP" or "DELETE FROM #TEMP WHERE.." is faster?

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I am wondering which one is much faster in THEORY?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @ControlOrderList )
BEGIN
    SET @RowNumber= (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @ControlOrderList)
    ...
    DELETE @ControlOrderList WHERE id=@RowNumber
END
```

or is this much faster?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @ControlOrderList )
BEGIN
    SET @RowNumber= (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @ControlOrderList)
    ...
    DELETE TOP 1 @ControlOrderList 
END
```

And is it secure to use DELETE TOP 1? Can I trust SQL-SERVER to delete the row that I got in "SELECT TOP 1 ....." ?

Comment: Does the second statement actually work? To compare queries just look at their actual execution plans and see which has the lowest operator cost

Comment: Don't use `top N` without specifying an order - in second case you have no guarantee that you'll hit same row.

Comment: I'd suggest you stop asking us to help you learn thousands of "X is faster than Y" rules, since there are usually lots of nuances, and you don't write well performing code by memorizing thousands of rules. You do it by writing *clear* code that does the correct task, and then *measure* the performance. If it meets your *requirements*, stop worrying about whether you could have written it faster. Or, to put it another way, please read Eric Lippert's [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: the second statement is much faster than the first one. and I think the second one works

Comment: This is very subjective question there are many factors which can change results . ie what is the amount of data in the tables ..what are the index ..in general for large data set temp table perform better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is optimised for `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE)`, so switching to that should be quicker in theory

`SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @ControlOrderList` isn't deterministic as you have no `ORDER BY` clause. This means you aren't even guaranteed the first statement will delete the same row every time.

You would need to look at an execution plan, but I would guess that, assuming `id` is indexed, both would do the same thing once the order by is included.